# sending email from exec within php

Tags: php, email

I have few questions related to passing parameters as a variable to my mail command inside exec in pHP.

Here is the code that works:

```
exec('echo "This is mail tesing" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a myresults.csv abc@mymail.com  2>&1', $output2 );
```

What I want to do is:
1) Pass result as a variable e.g I am having another exec command in PHP for executing a python script that returns name of the resulting output file. This output file needs to be emailed.
2) The user enters his email address through website, so I want to pass that email address in /bin/mail command.

This does not work:

```
exec('echo "Test mail using mail" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a results.csv $varEmail  2>&1', $output2 );
```

Error displayed on webpage:

```
 Send options without primary recipient specified. [1] => Usage: mail -eiIUdEFntBDNHRVv~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users )
```

echoing the email address variable a.k.a echo $varEmail gives the email address entered by user.

I think, I don't know how to pass parameter as a variable in this command. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is `$varEmail` a bash or php variable? If php, use `"`s to interpolate strings/variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line you provided, the String containing the command given to exec is surrounded by simple quotes. Therefore, php variables inside that string are not replaced.
You can use this instead (concatenate `$varEmail` to the string using `.` ):

```
exec('echo "Test mail using mail" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a results.csv '.$varEmail.'  2>&1', $output2 );
```

Another solution would have been to use double quotes, but you would then have to escape double quotes of the shell command:

```
exec("echo \"Test mail using mail\" | /bin/mail -s \"Testing\" -a results.csv $varEmail  2>&1", $output2 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution you suggested itself worked for the email! Now,  need to try for the result attachment in mail.